# UFW Deny out on specific adapter except for LAN traffic, VPN usage

Tags: vpn, firewall, ufw, file-sharing

I have two interfaces on a VM, one is traffic going out to web on VPN adapter (proton0) and the other should allow lan traffic (ens160).  The rules make sense to me however, I cant ping a lan address as it returns an error of Operation not permitted.  Ping works on lan with ufw disabled.  I only know enough to make me dangerous by self taught methods.  What I'm really chasing is my Samba mounts are not working with UFW enabled.  What might I be doing wrong?

| Port | Action | Where |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8081 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 80 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 53 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 5000 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 22 | ALLOW | 192.168.1.0/24 |
| 8989 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 7878 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 8686 | ALLOW | Anywhere |
| 8081 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 80 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 53 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 5000 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 8989 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 7878 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
| 8686 (v6) | ALLOW | Anywhere (v6) |
|  |  |  |
| Anywhere | ALLOW OUT | Anywhere on proton0 |
| Anywhere | DENY OUT | Anywhere on ens160 |
| 192.168.1.0/24 | ALLOW OUT | Anywhere on ens160 |
| Anywhere (v6) | ALLOW OUT | Anywhere (v6) on proton0 |
| Anywhere (v6) | DENY OUT | Anywhere (v6) on ens160 |

Answer (score 0):

After many hours of learning I found a solution but am not sure if it violates best security practices.  I inserted a rule above Anywhere Deny Out ens160.  The rule is 192.168.1.0/24 Allow Out ens 160.